# counting the alphabets from input

Tags: java

I need to write a code in java, which will take the input as a string from the user and will print the count of repetition of each alphabet. I Ihave written the code but not got the correct output.

```
input:ppooj
output:p1,o2,j1
```

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        System.out.println("ENTER ANY STRING");
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] arr= new String [5];

        for(int i=0; i<5 ;i++ )
        {
            arr[i]= sc.next();
            // getting input
        }

        for ( int i=0;i<5;i++){
            System.out.print(""+ arr[i]);
        }

        int count=1;
        int rep=0;
        int i=0;

        for ( i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            //traverse 
            System.out.println("in first loop" + ""+ arr[i]);

            for(int k=i+1; k<5;k++)
            {
                System.out.println("" + arr[k]);

                //matching with each and every one
                if(arr[i]==arr[k])
                {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("got the match" + count);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(arr[i]+count+",");
            count=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are **letters**, not alphabets. Alphabet is a set of letters in a language like English A-Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlphaCount {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); 
    char[] chArray = str.toCharArray();
    for(char c : chArray){
        if(map.containsKey(c)){
            map.put(c, map.get(c)+1);
        }
        else{
            map.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
    for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.print(entry.getKey() + "" + entry.getValue()+" ");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hi @Pooja have imported all the required classes??

Comment: Hi @poojasharma, Basically Map is used to store object in key and value format and here i have taken it of type key=Character and value=Integer and i have converted the string to char array and traversing that array if Map has some entry with that particular character then i increase it count by one else i insert that entry into map object and after traversing that array i will get to know the number of times the character has appeared in that string. If you still have any confusion please feel free to call.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps.

1. Read input.
2. split the input to characters. (You can get the `char[]` from `String`)
3. Iterate the `char[]` and you can use `Map<Character,Integer>` to store character vs number of occurrences.
4. Now your map contains all characters with occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only alphabets, try this approach

Take an array of size 26

Assign array with 0

let the index be the alphabet position like 0-a, 1-b ... 25-z

oop through the input string and increment the respective index position like

```
 array[inputString.charAt(i)-'a']++;
```

Print the result accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use equals method to compare reference objects value. As sometimes it get struck in the heap. So, it is better to use equals method over "==" while comparing values of reference objects.

**Array** is a reference type object.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Test 
    {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        System.out.println("ENTER ANY STRING");
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);


        String[] arr= new String [5];

        for(int i=0; i<5 ;i++ )
        {
            arr[i]= sc.next();
            // getting input



        }

        for ( int i=0;i<5;i++){

            System.out.print(""+ arr[i]);


        }


        int count=1;
        int rep=0;
        int i=0;

      for ( i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
            //traverse 
           // System.out.println("in first loop" + ""+ arr[i]);

            for(int k=i+1; k<5;k++)
        {
             //   System.out.println("" + arr[k]);

                //matching with each and every one

            if(arr[i].equals(arr[k]))
            {
                count++;
                System.out.println("got the match" + count);


            }
        }
            System.out.println(arr[i]+count+",");
            count=1;


  }


    }

}
```

Try this code. You can modify it as per your requirement in the application.

Comment: The output is not totally correct By this:PPOKJgot the match2
P2,
P1,
O1,
K1,
J1,      it should be P2,o1,k1,j1

Answer (score 0):

You can try Map with String as the key like this:

```
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    // set value = 0 to characters from a-z.
    for( int i = 'a'; i < 'z'; i++ ){           
        map.put(String.valueOf((char)i), 0);
    }

    // supposed you have this as your input array. This should be read from file.
    String[] arr= {"p","p","o","o","j"};

    // count the duplicated characters.
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        map.put(arr[i],map.get (arr[i])+1);
    }

    // remove duplicated characters in array.
    List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arr)));

    // print result.
    for (String string : list) {
        System.out.print(string+map.get(string));
    }
```